# unable to create 3D model clone in threejs project

Tags: three.js, frontend

So I have recently started exploring threejs and am making a website with threejs. This threejs scene is suppose to load a black space with stars that will move towards the camera an re render once they pass by the camera which does work fine, but now I want to add 3D models like space shuttles to this project. The motive is to render bunch of space shuttles randomly and make them travel in a straight line, once they pass the camera pov they should re render at the start, I am not able to create there clone and randomly render them after successfully loaded the 3D model. I did write the code to achieve that but is not working.

```
import * as THREE from './three.js-master/three.js-master/build//three.module.js'
import { GLTFLoader } from './three.js-master/three.js-master/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js'
import { TrackballControls } from './three.js-master/three.js-master/examples/jsm/controls/TrackballControls.js'

let scene, camera, renderer, starGeo, stars, root, shuttles = [];

function init() {
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 10;
    camera.position.x = Math.PI / 2;

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    starGeo = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    const vertices = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 6000; i++) {
        const star = new THREE.Vector3(
            Math.random() * 600 - 300,
            Math.random() * 600 - 300,
            Math.random() * 600 - 300
        );
        star.velocity = 0;
        star.acceleration = 0.02;
        vertices.push(star.x, star.y, star.z);
    }
    starGeo.setAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));

    const sprite = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('/assets/star.jpg');
    const starMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
        color: 0xaaaaaa,
        size: 0.7,
        map: sprite,
        transparent: true,
        alphaTest: 0.5,
    });

    stars = new THREE.Points(starGeo, starMaterial);
    scene.add(stars);


    const loader = new GLTFLoader();
    loader.load('assets/low_poly_space_shuttle/scene.gltf', function(gltf) {
        console.log(gltf);
        root = gltf.scene;

        root.scale.set(0.001, 0.001, 0.001);

        const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
        const texture = textureLoader.load('assets/low_poly_space_shuttle/textures/Material_diffuse.jpeg', function() {
            const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: texture });
            root.traverse(function(node) {
                if (node.isMesh) {
                    node.material = material;
                }
            });
        });

        // ***************** Expiremental (should render multiple 3D models, but doesnt) 
        // When you do i < 3000 (some big number) it will start lagging. That means that some process is running in the background but the cloned models are not getting rendered. 

        for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            const shuttle = root.clone();
            shuttle.position.set(
                Math.random() * 600 - 300,
                Math.random() * 600 - 300,
                Math.random() * 600 - 300,
            );
            scene.add(shuttle);
            shuttles.push(shuttle);
        }
        // *****************


        scene.add(root);

        // const controls = new TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
        // function animate() {
        //     requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        //     controls.update();
        //     renderer.render(scene, camera);
        // }
        
        animate();
    }, function(xhr) {
        console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + "% loaded");
    }, function(error) {
        console.log('An error occurred');
    });
    const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 1);
    light.position.set(2, 2, 5);
    scene.add(light);

    animate();
}

function animate() {
    starGeo.attributes.position.array.forEach((_, index) => {
        const x = starGeo.attributes.position.array[index * 3];
        const y = starGeo.attributes.position.array[index * 3 + 1];
        const z = starGeo.attributes.position.array[index * 3 + 2];
  
        starGeo.attributes.position.array[index * 3 + 2] += 1.0; // Move towards the camera
        if (z > 300) {
            starGeo.attributes.position.array[index * 3 + 2] = -300; // Reset position once it goes beyond the screen
        }
    });
    starGeo.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;

    // makes the loaded model move in a straight line. 
    if(root != undefined) {
        root.position.z += 0.05;
    }

    // added as an expirement(should work, but dosent)
    shuttles.forEach((shuttle) => {
        // shuttle.position.z += 1;
        if(root != undefined) {
            shuttle.position.z += 0.05;
        }
        if(shuttle.position.z > 300) {
            shuttle.position.z = -300;
        }
    })

    
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
init();
```

this is the current state of my code and here

```
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            const shuttle = root.clone();
            shuttle.position.set(
                Math.random() * 600 - 300,
                Math.random() * 600 - 300,
                Math.random() * 600 - 300,
            );
            scene.add(shuttle);
            shuttles.push(shuttle);
        }
```

and

```
shuttles.forEach((shuttle) => {
        // shuttle.position.z += 1;
        if(root != undefined) {
            shuttle.position.z += 0.05;
        }
        if(shuttle.position.z > 300) {
            shuttle.position.z = -300;
        }
    })
```

code blocks should create multiple clones of the 3D model but is not.

IMP thing to know: (1) when increasing the value in the 'for' loop to create the clone to 10 to 3000(some big number), the website starts lagging. That suggest some processes are happing in the back but is not able to render the 3D model.
(2) There seems to be no issue with the model or the texture because the initial model loads perfectly.